# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I have created a autocomplete suggestion box which is working fine but the problem is when I use `if and else` and `console.log()` it shows an error in my console i.e `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if` I don't know why? How can I solve this issue? Please help me.

code:

```
$("#tag").tokenInput("<?php echo base_url(); ?>search_tag", {
    onResult: function(results){
        $.each(results, function (index, value) {
            value.name = if(value.client_img==''){ "<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/user.png'>" }else{ "<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/client_img/"+value.client_img+"'>" }+value.fname+" "+value.lname;
        });
        //return results;
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

Comment: An `if` block doesn't return a value; you can't use it on the right side of an assignment like that. You should search for "ternary operator," which does the kind of thing you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` should be earlier so that the results of the if/ else block are applied to the value.name property.

```
$.each(results, function (index, value) {
  if(value.client_img==''){ 
  value.name ="<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/user.png'>" 
  }else{
  value.name = "<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/client_img/"+value.client_img+"'>" +value.fname+" "+value.lname;
  }
});
```

or use a ternary operator

```
$.each(results, function (index, value) {
  value.client_img==''
   ? value.name ="<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/user.png'>" 
   : value.name = "<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/client_img/"+value.client_img+"'>" +value.fname+" "+value.lname;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @gavgrif  I have another question when I click on any auto-suggestion it also gets an image but I want the only name after select any `value.name`

Comment: sorry @darkshadow - i cant speak to that without seeing ot code involved.

Comment: @darkshadow  i don't think `}+value.fname+" "+value.lname` will work. It will give you syntax error for extra `}`.

Comment: @darkshadow  currently you are not getting the above error i mentioned because it seems always `if` block executed.

Comment: @AlivetoDie - thanks for picking that up - it was a holdover form the copying / pasting the OP that I didn't change - I have removed the "}" from both options of the solution - cheers :)